# Call function multiple time nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

I have following code, to insert passwords on a website.

```js
require('chromedriver');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();
driver.get('https://junusergin.github.io/hack-mich/login.html');
    
let dictionary = [123456, 123456789, 12345, "qwerty", "password", 12345678, 111111, 123123, 1234567890, 1234567, "qwerty123", "000000", "1q2w3e", "aa12345678", "abc123"];
    
function tryCombinations(combinations) {
    let index = 0;
    
    inputField = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('username'));
    driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'test')", inputField);
        
    inputField = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('password'));
    driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value',  '" + combinations[index] +"')", inputField);
        
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className('button')).click();
    
    index++;
}
```

If I start the Script, it paste the first password in the browser. I want now to put in each password from the array.

For this my idea was something like this:

```
dictionary.forEach(element => tryCombinations(element));
```

Does someone know, why it does not work?

Comment: something like setIntervall in nodejs

Comment: It could be because the button is not clickable by the time the second iteration comes around.  Does the page present an alert or disable the button or something when you fail the first password check?  Might need something like `driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();`

Comment: thanks for your answer. if I paste this inside my function, it won't load the page

Answer (score 0):

replace the dictionary foreach with this

```js
for (var i in dictionary) {
 tryCombinations(dictionary[i]);
}
```

Comment: This is the same, like the for each Loop. Does

Comment: So you want to replace the password field each time with x of dictionary?

Comment: yes right. I want to paste in for this one specific username any password from the dictionary. In my case it takes only the first, because index is 0 and then it won't paste any other passwords from the dictionary. I think it is anything specific from node.js or selenium?

Comment: If I could see exactly what I am working with maybe a video or a demo or more code then that would help me understand!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bSk1sJwI1WNkC9LAFSH69trhzf0dQyOw/view?usp=sharing